# Does the bluetooth address of Android device changes after some time?

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-bluetooth, mac-address, bluetoothadapter

I am asking this question because I want to create an application which stores the data of the user according to the Bluetooth address of their phones. We can share his profile according to that Bluetooth address using Bluetooth. Some people are saying that Bluetooth address is change after sometime. Is it true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Bluetooth Classic address stays the same. The LE address is random and stays the same while connected, but otherwise an Android device changes its LE address regularly. The address could be the same for a few connections, but will then change. This "feature" cannot be disabled. Also, an Android app is not allowed to know its own LE address. So use a Classic connection.